What effect does the placement of the reference symbol (ampersand) have in a simple loop?
I just started learning rust and I am confused about how the ampersand placement affects the program in the following examples. I understand that '&' indicates a reference to a variable, but I'm not sure how these examples differ.
Example 1, no ampersand:
let arr = [1,2,3];

for n in arr {
    println!("number {}", n);
}

Example 2, on the array definition:
let arr = &[1,2,3];

for n in arr {
    println!("number {}", n);
}

Example 3, in the for loop:
let arr = [1,2,3];

for n in &arr {
    println!("number {}", n);
}

All three of these examples produce the same output:
number 1
number 2
number 3

Is there any difference in how this code executes, or in its efficiency or memory consumption?

Godbolt is a great tool for finding the answers to questions like these, btw. Here's a side-by-side comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/dTsTb95fs

And if you want to be exhaustive, examples 2 and 3 can also use for &n in …

@Dai godbolt is most useful when using optimization. Without optimization, as in the link you've sent, the compiler produces hundreds of lines of assembly output, which is quite inscrutable, and particularly unhelpful to a beginner. The suggestion to use godbolt is thus misplaced in this instance.


Is there any difference in how this code executes, or in its efficiency or memory consumption?

For such a small example the difference will be immaterial. But the three examples are doing rather different things:

This is creating an array, then iterating it by value so the source array is copied into the iterator and n is an i32. Not great for large arrays (or arrays of large elements) as it has to copy a ton of data.

This is creating a slice then iterating on it, slices don't do iteration by value so n is an &i32, for small arrays and small elements it can be slightly less efficient than the previous, however it's a very general form of iteration which works in most cases, slices are very common in rust.

This is also creating an array, but it's then iterating by reference, so the array is not copied, and n is an &i32. It's essentially a shorthand for creating a slice from the array and iterating on that. Useful for arrays of !Copy objects, for a small array of small Copy objects a lot less so as it's mostly more indirections and stack data.



Well, technically both 2 and 3 create an array, not a slice.

It's also worth mentioning that println!() automatically (de-)references the values passed as format arguments, which explains the exact same output in all three cases. (Someone coming from other languages might expect that giving {} a reference would print the pointer or something to that effect.)
